# Issue in rotating 3D view of DICOM images using jogl

Tags: 3d, rotation, jogl, dicom

I am a newbie in jogl. I am coding for 3D rendering of DICOM images. While 3D rendering of images using jogl, I created crud 3D view. Steps followed are as follows:

1. Imported DICOM file stack.
2. Created BufferedImages from files.
3. Texture is created for each image.

   ```
       // Create a OpenGL Texture object
       for(int i=0;i<image.length;i++)
       {     
           textures[i] = AWTTextureIO.newTexture(GLProfile.getDefault(), image[i], false); 

           textureCoords = textures[i].getImageTexCoords();
           textureTop[i] = textureCoords.top();
           textureBottom[i] = textureCoords.bottom();
           textureLeft[i] = textureCoords.left();
           textureRight[i] = textureCoords.right();
       }
   ```
4. Created cube of these images by placing them one after another.

   ```
   int x=numberOfImages;
   gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS); 

   // To place stack back to front
   for(float i=-numberOfImages*0.0050f;x>0;i=i+0.01f){ 

       // Enables this texture's target in the current GL context's state.
       textures[currTextureFilter].enable(gl);
       // Bind the texture with the currently chosen filter to the current OpenGL graphics context.
       textures[currTextureFilter].bind(gl);
       gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS); // of the color cube

       gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, (0.1f+i));
       gl.glTexCoord2f(textureLeft[x], textureBottom[x]);
       gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, (0.1f+i)); // bottom-left of the texture and quad
       gl.glTexCoord2f(textureRight[x], textureBottom[x]);
       gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, (0.1f+i));  // bottom-right of the texture and quad
       gl.glTexCoord2f(textureRight[x], textureTop[x]);
       gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, (0.1f+i));   // top-right of the texture and quad
       gl.glTexCoord2f(textureLeft[x], textureTop[x]);
       gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, (0.1f+i));  // top-left of the texture and quad

       currTextureFilter =x;


       textures[currTextureFilter].disable(gl);

       x--;
       gl.glFlush();

       gl.glEnd();
   }
   ```
5. Given facilities to 3d image like rotation, zooming etc.

While rotating 3D view, light intensity of images decrease and at certain angle, black strip appears. When I zoom that portion it is showing gap in 2 images.
Am I going wrong in any step? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

[image: First View]
[image: On Rotation]
[image]

Comment: This is a very broad topic. There are whole books about volume rendering. Getting something displaying is easy. Doing it correctly and efficiently requires a lot more.

Comment: @Reto Koradi: I have gone through NEHE tutorials. On basis of that, I coded above. Will you please guide to make it correct and efficient? I am lacking in getting proper guidance. Can you please suggest me link, sites?

Comment: The results of my work in this area are documented here: http://retokoradi.com/volume-rendering/. I don't really explain implementation details, though, so it will probably not be very helpful in replicating the results. It's a fairly substantial piece of software, with some original parts that I have not shared anywhere.

Comment: Thank you.The link is very informative. I have work on DICOM images and   able to display 3D view of Bone, lungs. I worked on segmentation. It is in crud form. Can you please suggest me study material which will guide me for perfection.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw slices in a fixed direction relative to the dataset, this will work reasonably well as long as your viewing direction is more or less orthogonal to the slices. At other angles, results will increasingly deteriorate.

In the extreme case, where your viewing direction is in the same plane as the slices, you will basically see nothing, because you look at the polygons edge on.

As for how to do volume rendering correctly and efficiently, that's a very wide area. There are whole books about the topic. And partly very expensive commercial solutions, where many of them don't actually work all that well.

Just to give you a starting point: One basic approach is that you store the data in a 3D texture, and then draw slicing planes that are always orthogonal to the viewing direction.